# WP custom fields with php/javascript slown down my page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I have a custom field, called "The_Date". This custom field can be available in all posts, one or more times. So I use a script to get the informations from the custom fields off all posts.

After a while I found out that the "do_shortcode" of my custom field slow down my page really hard. This happend, if I load more then 10 custom fields from the same type at one page. Is wordpress firing to much php/js requests?

Thats my code:

```
    <?php
    // all meta value for "The Date"
    $pos = get_unique_post_meta_values('the_date', 'post'); 

    if($pos){
    foreach( $pos as $position){

    // run javascript inside custom field
    $position = do_shortcode( $position );


    echo $position . "\n";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend getting the relevant information from 'The_Date' field inside the Loop and adding it as an HTML-Entity (e.g. attribute, tag-content, whichever makes more sense in your case).

This should avoid DB-Lookups.

In case you store the Date in a "human readable" format and use the JavaScript for sorting, then i'd recommend switching to UNIX-Timestamps and only converting to a readable format upon display.

Comment: Thx for helping me ... but I also need the "shortcode" action, beacuse its not only "a date", there are also some deeper infromations inside this custom field.

Comment: Maybe running the do_shortcodes after the foreach on the parent element in the HTML-Structure will bring an performance improvement.